# Only one of two parameters added in upstream job works in downstream job

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have two Jenkins jobs.  The first has Groovy code using "Execute system Groovy script" in it to store a couple of pieces of data I need for the downstream job.

The downstream job is called in post-build actions, using "Trigger parameterized build on other projects".  In the build triggers for that downstream job, I've tried including both of these options:

"Current build parameters"
"Build on the same node"

In the groovy code for the parent project, I can see that it's setting both of the parameters correctly using `println`.

The downstream job has "This project is parameterized" checked, and I've created string parameters for both of the parameters set in the upstream job.

The downstream job calls a batch file that does a bunch of post-build stuff.

**groovy code:**

```
def pa = new ParametersAction([new StringParameterValue("SERVICE_VERSION", serviceversion)], ["SERVICE_VERSION"])
Thread.currentThread().executable.addAction(pa)

def pa2 = new ParametersAction([new StringParameterValue("PROJ_BUILD_NUMBER", projbuildnumber)], ["PROJ_BUILD_NUMBER"])
Thread.currentThread().executable.addAction(pa2)
```

I would expect that I would be able to use both `%SERVICE_VERSION%` and `%PROJ_BUILD_NUMBER%` in the batch file, and they would both have the values set in the upstream job.

In the upstream job, if I `println` the two values, I get:

```
%SERVICE_VERSION% = 1.0.0
%PROJ_BUILD_NUMBER% = 225
```

However, in the downstream job, only `%SERVICE_VERSION%` is available.

```
ECHO SERVICE_VERSION=%SERVICE_VERSION%
SERVICE_VERSION=1.0.0

ECHO PROJ_BUILD_NUMBER=%PROJ_BUILD_NUMBER%
PROJ_BUILD_NUMBER=
```

Weirdly, if I swap the order of the two `addAction()` calls, neither of them are available.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question by reworking Trigger Parameterized Build to pass specific parameters and now it's working.  Yay, me!  [Trigger Parameterized Build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXMEa.png)